# Separate docker resources into different namespaces

Tags: docker

I would like to separate home resources from work resources, something like `<change to namespace work>` and then:

`docker container ls` - prints containers in work namespace

`docker container run` - runs container in work namespace

I tried to use docker context but it looks like it has different goals.

Comment: Please, if you downvote the question, write at least short info in comment why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker doesn't have any built-in support for this.  All images and containers are in a flat namespace, and there's no way to segregate one group of containers from another.

If you're using a VM-based solution (especially something built on Docker Machine, Docker Toolbox, or the minikube Kubernetes environment) you could start a separate VM for each "context".  That comes with some obvious downsides (each VM has a fixed memory and disk allocation, for example) but it would achieve the segregation you're looking for.